# Mock a method call that is in the same class i'm testing, is it really code smell?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test a service class (responsible for calling the repository layer and do some operations if needed), basically, this is the class I'm trying to test

```
class CarServiceImpl{
  public Car findById(String id){
      //call repository layer to find a car
  }

  public void deleteById(String id){
      Car car = this.findById(id);
      if(car != null){ 
          //Call repository layer to update the car
      }else{
          Throw NotFOundException();
      }
  }
}
```

As you can see I call the findById method on the deleteById method, so my questions are.

1. is it really code smell to call a method on the same class? I don think I should create a separate class to find a car by id.
2. how can I mock the call to "findById" on the "deleteById" method, if I use `Mockito.when(carServiceImpl.findById("car1")).thenReturn(carModel);`
   it stills call the method so i'll need to mock the call to respository for finding by id too, even when i already tested the method findById.

Comment: What about leaving the `findById` operation to the callers of `deleteById`? If any1 passes an id that doesn't exist the repository will throw an appropriate exception and your `CarServiceImpl` can catch and transform (if needed) that exception in something your application understands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a smell and you can partially mock `Car` like so:

```
String carId = "...";
Car car = ...;

CarServiceImpl car = mock(CarServiceImpl.class);
when(car.findById(carId)).thenReturn(car);    
when(car.deleteById(carId)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

**But** if you can allow `deleteById()` to execute the 'real method' then your test must already have a repository in which case letting `findById()` be a 'real call' is simple and improves the quality of your test coverage at ~no additional cost. The fact that you have already tested `findById()` doesn't mean that you *shouldn't* test it again, indirectly, as part of `deleteById()`.

I would suggest that you do either or both of the following:

- Unit test `Car` by giving it a mocked `repository` and using mocked expectations and verifications to test all of its methods
- Functional/Acceptance test `Car` by giving it a real repository and using real invocations on the underlying store to assert actual results for each of its methods

On a separate note, I'm guessing the idea of injecting a repository into a domain object is a deliberate use of the "active record" pattern where your entities know how to CRUD themselves. This *could* be considered a code smell; it breaches the SRP and could be held to be a poor separation of concerns because the domain object knows about two things: its own state and how to persist itself.

Answer (score 2):

You want your test setup and test code to be as "minimalistic" as possible. In that sense, the other answer is correct in saying: if you can test `deleteById()` without a special setup then go for that.

And would it turn out that `findById()` is by itself a "huge" thing that requires a lot of test setup - then I would rather step back and consider putting the content of this method into a *distinct* class - some kind of `CarIdentityService`.

Meaning: very often when we start making *test* code more complex - the better answer is to step back and change the design of our production code. In your case, you might want to push the whole `findById()` code into a distinct class - and now you can simply **mock** that finder object  within your `CarService` class.

And just for the record: `CarIdentityService` could be a local or inner class of `CarService`. But introducing it might allow you to streamline you implementation and avoid getting into the spy business.

Comment: Nice elaboration on how to refactor the finder call.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, great example when I need to separate the code to another class but think I'm sticking to just one class for this case

Comment: It could be a problem that I am going through. While I understand the solution is to refactor the code and move the method in question to a helper service which is mocked, but is there any other way around that,and also I don't want to spy on that method.